# Tangent Planes. Have a quiz tomorrow and confused on one thing.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

There is one practice question in which I have to find the points on a graph z = 3x^2 - 4y^2 at which the vector n = <3,2,2> is the normal vector to the tangent plane.
Here is how far I got:

```
z = 3x^2-4y^2   n = <3,2,2>         gradient of w = <6x, -8y, -1>
0 = 3x^2-4y^2-z = w(x,y,z)

6x = 3      -8y = 2       -1 = 2
```

The answer is supposedly -1/4, 1/8, 1/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a point where the gradient of $w$ is *equal* to $\vec n$. That's too restrictive. You have to look for a point where the gradient of $w$ is *parallel* to $\vec n$. After all, if $\vec n$ is a normal vector at some point, then $2\vec n$ is also a normal vector at the same point.

In other words, you need to introduce a new variable $k$ and solve
$$
\cases{6x = 3k\\-8y = 2k\\-1 = 2k}
$$
Once you've found $x$ and $y$ from this equation, you can insert this into the original expression for the graph to find which $z$ coordinate gives you a point on the surface.

Comment: Apparently I need to wait a couple minutes to select "best answer" but thanks a lot. This made a lot of sense. Now I can finally go to sleep.

Comment: @MaxSchwartz You can avoid introducing a new variable by setting the cross product of the gradient and target normal to zero.